# Can't access uri segment in controller of codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, parameters, uri

What would be the best way to get uri segment via parameter in controller? i have used following code but not working

uri as

> http://localhost/home/23

```
class Home extends CI_Controller
{


   public function index($para){
    echo $para;
   }
}
```

Above uri results in 404 page not found error.How to solve such problem and get the id as parameter in index function.

Comment: $this->uri->segment('4'); not sure about ('3') or ('4')

Comment: My old apps worked in above code but now not working i just need reason for the problem

Comment: Is base_url defined correctly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write routing in your `routes.php` file.

File path : `application/config/routes.php`

```
$route['home/(:any)'] = 'home/index/$1';

OR

$route['home/index/(:any)'] = 'home/index/$1';
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: You can used OR option in my answer.